# Use finished Templates

Tags: django

i have a question. 
Im working on a Project and i finished the Logic Part. So this was my first Project with Django and Web in generell. And my .html files are really really bad! So, now i want to change this. Work with a new Template and rework this a bit.

The first "base.html" was from W3Schools and now i want to use a bootstrap Theme. The Question is, how can i import the Files?

So i know that i have to put css,js Files into my static Folder and then import them into my base.html.

The Thing now is, that i have much Folders and Files. I have a css, img, js, scss and vendor Folder and some Files like package.json, gulpfile.js and stuff like that.

In these Folders are files like .css or .min.css, .js and .min.js, much scss Files and in the Vendor File are even more Folders with Files!

So the question now is, how can i import this good? That i dont destroy anything, which File should be in css, js and ?scss? dont know if i need a file for this in django! And how can i import them correct? Maybe anyone has an Example?

Would be really nice if someone can help me a bit with this!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For now, don't use any of those downloaded files, and use the hosted versions - it will be simpler. From Bootstrap's [introduction](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/):

> Copy-paste the stylesheet `<link>` into your `<head>` before all other stylesheets to load our CSS.
>
> ```html
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
> ```

And:

> Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function. Specifically, they require jQuery, Popper.js, and our own JavaScript plugins. Place the following s near the end of your pages, right before the closing  tag, to enable them. jQuery must come first, then Popper.js, and then our JavaScript plugins.
>
> ```html
> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
> <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
> <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
> ```

Note, you might not need the `popper.min.js` - read the instructions on that page.

Once you get that working, you could replace them with local files if you want. In the downloaded Bootstrap directory, they'll be in `dist/css/` and `dist/js/`. You'll also need to download jQuery (or keep linking to it remotely).